# Fedora 12 can see wireless network, but It cannot connect

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora-12

I installed Fedora 12 on my old desktop, and while Fedora 12 shows wireless networks that it could connect to, everytime I try to connect to that network, the connection fails, I have made sure that the WEP key and everything is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to connect?  How are you trying to connect?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to unsecured networks?

Comment: What does the system log say as you try to connect?